# ZK: enable button in listcell only for the selected item of a listbox

Tags: button, listbox, zk, zul

In the next listbox I load elements with template:

```
<listbox model="@load(vm.resAccepted)" selectedItem="@bind(vm.selResAccepted)">
  <template name="model">
    <listitem>
      <listcell label="@load(each.eventName)" />
      <listcell label="@load(each.userName)" />
      <listcell>
        <button image="/img/button_mail.png"/>
      </listcell>
    </listitem>
  </template>
</listbox>
```

My goal is to enable the button of the listitem **ONLY** for the row the user selects.

To do this, I try

```
<button disabled="@load(vm.selResAccepted.id=each.id?'false':'true')" />
```

checking if the unique field **id** is the same of the selected element, but it fails.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eq` for equals comparison:

`<button disabled="@load(vm.selResAccepted.id eq each.id?'false':'true')" />`

or maybe even better: disabled when selected item is not the current item

`<button disabled="@load(vm.selResAccepted ne each)" />`

here `ne` is not equal